# How to cut and paste

Tags: support, feature-request, comments

It has happened a few times that I have wanted to move someone else's answer from the comments to an answer, when the poster implicitly does not wish to do so (by not responding after a days-old request) or explicitly declines to do so.  Of course, I think that the proper thing to do in such cases is to wait a decent interval and mark the post community wiki.  Anyway, this is not my question.

It is tough to cut and paste a heavily marked up comment, and I usually wind up simply manually re-typing it.  I know that I can right click on an individual MathJax object and see the code that produced it, but is there any way to see, or otherwise to C&P, the source for an entire comment?

I am not sure if I am asking for support with an existing feature, or a feature request for a missing but surely useful feature, so I put both tags.

Comment: Some suggestions can be found here: [How to copy mixture of text and latex formulas in a comment?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3234) (Mathematics Meta) From the possibilities listed there, the bookmarklet is really quick. However, it only works for comments under a question (not for comments under an answer). Maybe also other [posts linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3234) might be useful.

Comment: It might be also worth checking Meta Stack Exchange: [Is there a way to view a comment's source?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203390) (And maybe also [the linked questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/203390).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak, thanks!  It sure seems like my question is a duplicate of your first linked one.  Do you agree?

Comment: Well, except we do not have cross-site duplicates - it's not on Meta Mathoverflow.

Comment: You *should* retype it and, in fact, rewrite it. Copy and paste of a comment usually does not make a good answer (even if it can give the gist of the main idea).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, I can buy that this is generally true, but the specific example that motivated it was [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/293994) copied nearly *literatim* from comments by [alpoge](https://mathoverflow.net/users/12138/alpoge), which is, I think, a counterexample.

Comment: All right, there are surely exceptions, but the question is if they are frequent enough to warrant a special software support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certainly legitimate reasons when it is useful to copy text of a comment. As Emil Jeřábek said, it is not clear whether they are frequent enough to be integrated in Stack Exchange software.

> All right, there are surely exceptions, but the question is if they are frequent enough to warrant a special software support. -- [Emil Jeřábek](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3665/how-to-cut-and-paste#comment16128_3665)

If you think that such feature can be useful you should probably upvote the feature request on Meta Stack Exchange: [Is there a way to view a comment's source?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203390)

---

I will summarize some of the methods how to copy comments. There are certainly many possibilities how to do this, I'll mention the ones I have at least tried.

I will also refer to the answers here: [Is there a way to view a comment's source?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203390) on Meta Stack Exchange and [How to copy mixture of text and latex formulas in a comment?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3234) on Mathematics Meta.

Clearly, if the comment contains only plaintext, it can be copied directly from the browse. It is more problematic what to do if the comment also uses some [MarkDown](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/markdown/info) and [MathJax](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/mathjax/info). We can try whether various methods work on [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/295897/contragredient-of-a-cuspidal-representation#comment735801_295897) which contains both.

There is a bookmarklet for this available among [NormalHuman's Stackmarklets](https://normalhuman.github.io/stackmarklets/) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20180401234620/https://normalhuman.github.io/stackmarklets/)). In Google Chrome I had no problems with using it - all I needed to do was to drag the bookmarklet to the bookmark bar and then I was able to start using it.

The disadvantage is that in this way you can only copy the comments under *the question*. Also, it won't work if the question is closed, since the comment is copied into the answer box.

In this way I get:

`In addition to [@PaulBroussous](https://mathoverflow.net/a/295954)'s nice answer, another easy way to make this false is if ($\pi$ is not self dual and) $G$ <i>has</i> no (non-trivial) characters, as happens, for example, for $G = \mathrm{SL}_2(F)$ (at least if $\mathrm{char}(F) \ne 2$). -- [LSpice](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/295897/contragredient-of-a-cuspidal-representation#comment735801_295897)`

> In addition to [@PaulBroussous](https://mathoverflow.net/a/295954)'s nice answer, another easy way to make this false is if ($\pi$ is not self dual and) $G$ *has* no (non-trivial) characters, as happens, for example, for $G = \mathrm{SL}_2(F)$ (at least if $\mathrm{char}(F) \ne 2$). -- [LSpice](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/295897/contragredient-of-a-cuspidal-representation#comment735801_295897)

You can also simply view the source of the page (Ctrl+U in Google Chrome) and view the text of the comment of the comment in this way. If there are many comments, you can use [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com) to see the version of the question with all comments displayed. Notice that you get things in HTML, while the bookmarklet mentioned above changes *some* of it to MarkDown.

`In addition to <a href="https://mathoverflow.net/a/295954">@PaulBroussous</a>&#39;s nice answer, another easy way to make this false is if ($\pi$ is not self dual and) $G$ <i>has</i> no (non-trivial) characters, as happens, for example, for $G = \mathrm{SL}_2(F)$ (at least if $\mathrm{char}(F) \ne 2$).`

> In addition to [@PaulBroussous](https://mathoverflow.net/a/295954)'s nice answer, another easy way to make this false is if ($\pi$ is not self dual and) $G$ *has* no (non-trivial) characters, as happens, for example, for $G = \mathrm{SL}_2(F)$ (at least if $\mathrm{char}(F) \ne 2$).

It is also possible to use [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/145005/view-a-single-comment-based-on-id-or-url?CommentId=735801) with comment id or comment link. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203390/is-there-a-way-to-view-a-comments-source/267979#267979) for more details.

`In addition to [@PaulBroussous](https://mathoverflow.net/a/295954)'s nice answer, another easy way to make this false is if ($\pi$ is not self dual and) $G$ *has* no (non-trivial) characters, as happens, for example, for $G = \mathrm{SL}_2(F)$ (at least if $\mathrm{char}(F) \ne 2$).`

> In addition to [@PaulBroussous](https://mathoverflow.net/a/295954)'s nice answer, another easy way to make this false is if ($\pi$ is not self dual and) $G$ *has* no (non-trivial) characters, as happens, for example, for $G = \mathrm{SL}_2(F)$ (at least if $\mathrm{char}(F) \ne 2$).

Here both url and italics have been converted to MarkDown.

Comment: Also, the iOS StackExchange app does not allow me to paste in comment fields at all.  That seems worth fixing.

Comment: @MattF. That seems only marginally related to the topic at hand. In any case, this thread seems to be about the problem you mentioned: [iOS 11 - unable to paste into comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299803).